# How to merge dataframe with time range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to map time category from the other time range dataframe.
Here is the Time Range Dataframe. The time between "Start" and "End" is categorized into each "Weeks".

```
       Start        End  Weeks
0 2019-08-30 2019-10-03      1
1 2019-10-04 2019-10-31      2
2 2019-11-01 2019-11-28      3
```

Here is my time dataframe.

```
        Date
0 2019-09-06
1 2019-10-13
2 2019-10-12
3 2019-11-04
```

Here is the output I want. You can see that each date is categorized into the corresponding "Weeks" based on Time Range Dataframe.

```
        Date Weeks
0 2019-09-06     1
1 2019-10-13     2
2 2019-10-12     2
3 2019-11-04     3
```

My code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
# Date Range dataframe
Date_Range = {'Start':[datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 30, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 4, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0)],
              'End':[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 3, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 31, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 28, 0, 0)],
              'Weeks':[1,2,3],}
Date_Range_DF = pd.DataFrame(Date_Range)
print(Date_Range_DF)

# My dataframe
Date = {'Date':[datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 6, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 13, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 12, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 0, 0)]}
Date_DF = pd.DataFrame(Date)
print(Date_DF)


# Merge Dataframe
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = Date_Range
df2 = Date_Range_DF
df2.start, df2.End = pd.to_datetime(df2.Start), pd.to_datetime(df2.End)
filtered = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='Date', right_on='Start')
```

However, it keeps showing the erroe  `TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'dict'> was passed`

Please help me to find the bugs. Thank.

Comment: Is there any typo with date "2019-07-06"? The date is not in the given range.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step1**

make boundary list (`bins`)

```
bins = [Date_Range_DF.loc[0, 'Start'] - pd.Timedelta('1day')] + Date_Range_DF['End'].tolist()
```

`bins`

```
[Timestamp('2019-08-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-10-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-11-28 00:00:00')]
```

**Step2**

divide category by `pd.cut`(use boundary from `bins`)

```
s = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(Date_DF['Date']), bins=bins, labels=df1['Weeks'].tolist())
```

`s`

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
Name: Date, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1 < 2 < 3]
```

**Step3**

make `s` to `Weeks` column

```
Date_DF['Weeks'] = s
```

`Date_DF`

```
    Date        Weeks
0   2019-09-06  1
1   2019-10-13  2
2   2019-10-12  2
3   2019-11-04  3
```

if you don want that dtype of `Week`is category, use following code
for example make `int`

```
Date_DF['Weeks'] = s.astype('int')
```

---

**Other Way**

```
pd.merge_asof(Date_DF.sort_values('Date'), Date_Range_DF.drop('End', axis=1).rename(columns={'Start':'Date'}).sort_values('Date'))
```

you can get result `merge_asof`, but additional processing is required for dates later than '2019-11-28'

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the first way but get the error ```ValueError: bins must be of datetime64 dtype```.